# Buscar datos dentro url API, que tiene los datos a buscar dentro de llaves y otras llaves? Javascript

Tags: json, api

Muy buenas intento explicar mi problema:

Estoy intentando acceder a la api de 2 url, la primera funciona muy bien pero la segunda no es una array y los datos estan dentro de llaves y luego otra llave y luego la info. No se exactamente como buscarla dentro de tantas llaves aqui los ejemplos.

primera que funciona

```
const api_url = 'https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price'
async function precios() {
const response = await fetch(api_url);
const data = await response.json();

const {price, symbol} = data[1007];
console.log(textContent = price);
document.getElementById("kusamap").textContent = price;
document.getElementById("kusamas").textContent = symbol;
data.forEach(function(element, index){
    console.log(element, index);
})
```

Segunda con la data dentro de otras llaves

```
const api_url = 'https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens'
async function precios() {
const response = await fetch(api_url);
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
data.forEach(function(element, index){
    console.log(element, index);
})

}
```

he probado con muchas cosas, pero para hacer una busquedad en la segunda no encuentro ninguna forma de dejarlo asi de simple como la primera.
La idea es tener una caja en la cual escribir el criptoactivo y que me devuelva el precio y el nombre.

que seria algo asi

```
var texto_Derecho = document.getElementById("texto_lineasD");
var boton_Derecho = document.getElementById("botonD");
boton_Derecho.addEventListener("click", criptoactivo);


var texto_Izquierdo = document.getElementById("texto_lineasI");
var boton_Izquierdo = document.getElementById("botonI");
boton_Izquierdo.addEventListener("click", cantidadEnCripto);

function criptoactivo(params) {
const found = data.find(({symbol}) => symbol == texto_Derecho.value)
console.log(found);
}
function cantidadEnCripto(params) {
const found = data.find(({symbol}) => symbol == texto_Derecho.value);
console.log(texto_Izquierdo.value * found.price);
    
}
```

lo mas interesante que he encontrado es esto:

```
    Object.keys(data.data).forEach(key => console.log(key, data.data[key]));
```

luego he intentado hacer algo asi

```
const api_url = 'https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens'
async function precios() {
const response = await fetch(api_url);
const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data.data)) {
precios =  value;
    numero = key;
    let nueva = [];
    nueva = precios;
    function criptoactivo(params) {
        const found = nueva.find(({symbol}) => symbol == texto_Derecho.value)
        console.log(found);
    }

    var texto_Derecho = document.getElementById("texto_lineasD");
    var boton_Derecho = document.getElementById("botonD");
    boton_Derecho.addEventListener("click", criptoactivo);

    function criptoactivo(params) {
        Object.entries(data.data).map(ult => {
            const found = ult.find(({symbol}) => symbol === texto_Derecho.value)
            console.log(found);
        })
    }
    
}
}
precios();
```

INFO segun la web se entrega asi

```
Request
```

GET https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens

```
 Response
     {
           "updated_at": 1234567,              // UNIX timestamp
           "data": {
              "0x...": {                        // the address of the BEP20 token
                "name": "...",                  // not necessarily included for BEP20 tokens
                "symbol": "...",                // not necessarily included for BEP20 tokens
                "price": "...",                 // price denominated in USD
                "price_BNB": "...",             // price denominated in BNB
              },
          // ...
            }
          }
```

Pero aqui ya no me de la cabeza mas y admito fue mas un quita pon goglear quita pon goglear.
Espero que me puedan ayudar y gracias de antemano.
Tengo que decir algo soy muy muy novato llevo haciendo un curso online desde hace solo 2 semanas y aunque los ejercicios son muy buenos siempre intento hacer algo para mi dia a dia y con tan poco conocimiento es muy muy duro llevo aqui ya desde el finde, he buscado pero no encuentro a nadie con el mismo problemas.
Saludos
Jonathan